what is correct way to change data types before data analysis?
I have a road accident dataset and I want to analyze this dataset. But I am struggling with data types as all data types in dataset is float but data is int or categorical.



casualty
age




1.0
22.0


2.2
33.0



When I check data type for above column its float for both column. But in original casualty is categorical like fatal and serious and age is int. My teacher told me to apply one hot encoding  and when I apply one-hot encoding, it give bool data type but my teacher said that it should be categorical. Can some one please help
I apply One hot encoding but it give bool vales. I want to apply pone hot encoding but I need categorical data type

share your code please, we can't respond by guessing, tks

merge_casualty_accident_vehicle['sex_of_casualty'] = merge_casualty_accident_vehicle['sex_of_casualty'].astype('category')
